# how to fix navigation bar list items using customised css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am making a customized navigation bar for my website, but the list items do not show up as I wanted.

here's what I've tried [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/willson159/Lzhk74f6/7/). 
In my localhost i get [This Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdtWV.jpg).

Thanks for your time.

here's the html code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="top-nav-shadow">
<nav class="navbar bg-nav">
<div class="navbar-brand">
Contact: <a  href="#">+91 xxxxxxxxxx or xxxxxxxxx </a>
</div>
<div class="top-nav-logo">
<img src="images/IN.png">
<img class="img2" src="images/PV.png">
</div>
</nav>
</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="nav-shadow">
<nav class="navbar bg-nav-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
          <img src="images/logo.png" class="navbar-logo">
    </div>
    <div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>   
</div>   
</nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.bg-nav
{
background: #008080; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #008080 0%, #008080 80%, #ffffff 81%, #ffffff 81%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #008080 0%,#008080 80%,#ffffff 81%,#ffffff 81%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #008080 0%,#008080 80%,#ffffff 81%,#ffffff 81%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#008080', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
border-top:1px solid #008080;
max-height:30px;
}
.bg-nav-inverse
{
background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 17%, #008080 18%, #008080 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 17%,#008080 18%,#008080 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 17%,#008080 18%,#008080 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#008080',GradientType=1 );
color:black;
border-bottom:1px solid #008080;
max-height:50px;
}
.top-nav-shadow
{   margin-top:3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.nav-shadow
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
.navbar-logo
{
    max-width:11%;;
    margin-top:-45px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-bottom:-20px;
}
.top-nav-logo
{
    margin-top:-18px;
}
.top-nav-logo img
{
    max-height:60px;
    margin-left:30px;

}
.top-nav-logo .img2
{
    max-height:73px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.navbar-brand
{
    font-family:Aharoni;
    font-size:18px;
    color:white;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:-48px;
}

.navbar-brand a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-size:20px;

}
.navbar-brand a: hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#CCC;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
    .bg-nav
{
background: #008080; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #008080 0%, #008080 63%, #ffffff 64%, #ffffff 64%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #008080 0%,#008080 63%,#ffffff 64%,#ffffff 64%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #008080 0%,#008080 63%,#ffffff 64%,#ffffff 64%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#008080', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.bg-nav-inverse
{
background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 37%, #008080 38%, #008080 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 37%,#008080 38%,#008080 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 37%,#008080 38%,#008080 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#008080',GradientType=1 );
color:black;
}

}
```

I am desiring an output as  [This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUUXC.png)

I have posted all that I have done, so i would like you to suggest me where i am doing the mistake.

Comment: What's the desired output for it ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO Willson. Do you think you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? What's the desired output ? Where is your CSS ?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you set your navbar to `position: fixed` but forgot to compensate its original height, either set a `padding-top` on your body equivalent to your navbar's height or set a min-height on a non fixed navbar container.

Comment: @Techie_T  , thank you so much for reply. Please check my code again, I have edited with everything i have done. And also the desired result as well

Comment: @Jake please check my codes again i have updated with all that i have

Comment: Simply set your navigation items (`<li>`s) to `.nav-item` (see Bootstrap 4 Navbar guide [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some spare time and was curious about Bootstrap so I integrated your desired output the way I thought best (using Bootstrap for the first time haha).

Code snippet :

```css
@charset "utf-8";

.navbar {
 border: 1px solid #008080;
 border-width: 1px 0;
 box-shadow: 0px -4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75), 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

.navbar-contact,
.nav {
 background: #008080;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar-contact {
 max-height: 29px;
}

.bottom {
 margin-top: -30px;
}

/* White Angles (Common) */

.nav:before,
.navbar-contact:after {
    content: "";
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 2em; height: 2.5em;
    transform: skew(-30deg);
}

/* .navbar-contact angle position */

.navbar-contact:after {
    right: -1em;
    top: 0;
}

/* .nav angle position */

.nav:before {
    left: -1em;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<html>
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar p-0">
   <div class="top d-flex w-100">
     <div class="px-2 navbar-contact text-white position-relative flex-grow-1">Contact: <a class="text-white" href="#">+91 xxxxxxxxxx or xxxxxxxxxx </a></div>
       <div class="pt-1 pr-3 d-flex mt-auto bg-white position-relative">
        <img class="position-relative ml-2 mr-1" src="http://computervision.in/images/IN.png" height="50">
        <img class="position-relative mx-3" src="http://computervision.in/images/PV.png" height="55">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom d-flex w-100">
          <a href="" class="navbar-brand mr-0">
                <img src="http://computervision.in/images/logo.png" height="60">
          </a>
          <ul class="nav mt-auto flex-grow-1 pl-4 position-relative">
           <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link text-white active" href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Courses</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/3L7tmbxk/

**To sum it up** :

- I transformed your gradient backgrounds into pseudo element angles. They are placed relatively to their containers for better responsivity and take advantage of Bootstrap 4 flexbox implementation.
- I used Bootstrap classes as much as possible but I think you could improve it even more. It's my first time using it so I don't know all the possible configurations and all the available classes.
- I set the height of your images directly into their `img` tag.

Comment: thank you for this snippet, it was really helpful, however I am not able to collapse those list items while on a lower  screen size

Comment: You couldn't either in your original JSFiddle. Check out the [navbar component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/), you'll need to add a `<button>` with the class `.navbar-toggler` and an `id` that targets your navigation and you'll need to use the classes `.navbar-collapse .collapse` on your navigation and an id that matches the one used in the button's target.

Comment: thank you so much Jake Your answers are really helpful, but I already did that. The problem is that the list items are collapsed even in the full screen mode.

Comment: Actually I am new to front end development, in fact i am a student. Therefore I am facing  a lot troubles while fixing bugs. Thank you for giving your time on me.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your CSS as your desired output. I will suggest you to mustn't use **margins in negative**. It is not a appropriate way to make a good layout.

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.bg-nav
{
background: #008080; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #008080 0%, #008080 80%, #ffffff 81%, #ffffff 81%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #008080 0%,#008080 80%,#ffffff 81%,#ffffff 81%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #008080 0%,#008080 80%,#ffffff 81%,#ffffff 81%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#008080', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
border-top:1px solid #008080;
max-height:30px;
}
.bg-nav-inverse
{
background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 17%, #008080 18%, #008080 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 17%,#008080 18%,#008080 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 17%,#008080 18%,#008080 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#008080',GradientType=1 );
color:black;
border-bottom:1px solid #008080;
max-height:50px;
}
.top-nav-shadow
{   margin-top:3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.nav-shadow
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
.navbar-logo
{
    max-width:11%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
}
.top-nav-logo
{
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  float:right;
}
.top-nav-logo img
{
    max-height:44px;
    margin-left:30px;
}
.top-nav-logo .img2
{
    max-height:47px;
    padding-left:30px;
}
.navbar-brand
{
    font-family:Aharoni;
    font-size:18px;
    color:white;
    padding:0px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.navbar-brand a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-size:20px;

}
.navbar-brand a: hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#CCC;
}

.nav.navbar-nav{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 220px;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav.navbar-nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
        margin-right: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
    .bg-nav
{
background: #008080; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #008080 0%, #008080 63%, #ffffff 64%, #ffffff 64%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #008080 0%,#008080 63%,#ffffff 64%,#ffffff 64%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #008080 0%,#008080 63%,#ffffff 64%,#ffffff 64%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#008080', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.bg-nav-inverse
{
background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 37%, #008080 38%, #008080 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 37%,#008080 38%,#008080 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 37%,#008080 38%,#008080 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#008080',GradientType=1 );
color:black;
}

}
```